# Распаковка/упаковка apk

Tags: python, apk

Можно ли распаковать/запаковать файл apk файл в python?

Comment: В смысле? Просто, "буквально": `unzip program.apk` `zip program.apk`. (bash)

Answer (score 0):

В смысле? Просто, "буквально":

```
import os
os.system('unzip program.apk')
```

```
import os
os.system('zip program.apk')
```